# Run an Executable file before Setup starts

Tags: winforms, setup-project

i have a winform application and i want to create setup for it.my application need an exe file to install in machine in order to it can work correctly. so i want to install that exe file before my application setup starts.i have used Installer Class but it runs the exe file after the setup has finished.
how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can add this EXE as a custom prerequisite:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77z6b8tz(VS.80).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429(VS.80).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429.aspx

After generating the package manifests, you can add all these files (including the package) in a separate folder in the Visual Studio prerequisites folder, for example:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages
```

You can then select the prerequisite in your setup project property page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But i have solved my problem with InstallerClass.